# Best way to display a custom map in Flash (AS3)?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, google-maps, bing-maps

I'm trying to take a game map and put it into say Google Maps or Bing Maps or whatever is best for my Flash app. I've tried the Google Maps API but it has some limitations in Flash and I can't seem to find a tile cutter that doesn't mangle the base tiles with compression.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the ideas of Google Maps and rolling my own solution. I basically just resized the image to several resolutions and cut them up.